# VSCode C++ Intellisense can't discern C++20 features

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, c++20

I try to run codes like

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string str = "This is a string";
    std::cout << str.starts_with("name");
}
```

But intellisense will give out an error

> "std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits,
> std::allocator>" has no member "starts_with" C/C++(135) [6,9]

And It still can be build and produce a correct result.
Also it can find implementation in header file.
But the macro `__cplusplus` is defined as `201703L`
I've already added a command `-std=c++20` when building, why this happened?

Compiler: minGW 11.2 compiled by msys2

Comment: you have to fill in the `c_cpp_properties.json`

Comment: @rioV8 I have already added , it is "cppStandard": "c++20"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Assuming you are using [Microsoft's C/C++ extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools), you must configure the extension to use C++ 20 standard for intellisense.

The easiest way to do this is to add the line `"C_Cpp.default.cppStandard": "c++20"` to your *settings.json* file. You can also find the setting in the GUI under the name *"Cpp Standard"*. Selecting `c++20` from its dropdown will achieve the same result.

Note that this setting is, by default, set as a global user defaults. You can configure it per-workspace by selecting the *Workspace* tab in the settings GUI and changing that Cpp Standard dropdown to `c++20`.

As for why adding the -std=c++20 flag didn't work: `-std=c++20` just tells your compiler which standard to use to build your code. 'Intellisense' does not receive this flag because it is a separate tool from the compiler and is therefore not required to support all the standards the compiler supports. It may support less even, although Intellisense tools usually support as current a standard as possible. Therefore the language standard for Intellisense must be configured separately from the compiler (in this case).

*Final Note*: After changing the setting, try closing and re-opening VS Code. In my experience changing the language standard setting can cause some weirdness to happen. Closing and re-opening VS Code seems to ensure the setting changes take full effect.

Comment: Reloading the window is a bit faster than closing and opening.

Comment: True, that’s definitely a better option. Forgot about that