# VScode C++ IntelliSense doesn't suggest c++20 features

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, intellisense, clang++

I'm using clang++14 compiler.
I've tried to write following code:

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

int main() {
    std::set<int> st = {1, 2, 3, 4, 6};
    if (st.contains(6)) {
        std::cout << "contains!\n";
    }
}
```

But Intellisense's pop-up window says `class "std::__1::set<int, std::__1::less<int>, std::__1::allocator<int>>" has no member "contains"C/C++(135)` \

I've tried to set up IntelliSense, `settings.json` file looks like:

```json
{
    "C_Cpp.default.cppStandard": "c++20",
}
```

Also I've chosen C++20 standard in **C/C++: Edit configurations (UI)** window in vscode

But it doesn't help. Am I missing something?

**UPD:**
Also I have `"cppStandard": "c++20"` and `"intelliSenseMode": "macos-clang-x64"` lines set in `c_cpp_properties.json`

Comment: I know that there's a question where everyting I did was proposed as solution (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70457722/vscode-c-intellisense-cant-discern-c20-features), but it seems like this solution didn't help me.

Comment: It's probably only IntelliSense that has not been updated. As long as your program compiles, just igore IntelliSense.

Comment: `c_cpp_properties.json` is the place to edit the Intellisense settings if you are using the default mode (without code-runner). This explains the 3 json files involved: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac)

Comment: @drescherjm, also I have `"cppStandard": "c++20"`  and `"intelliSenseMode": "macos-clang-x64"` lines set in `c_cpp_properties.json`, but it doesn't help

Comment: Then it's probably what @TedLyngmo said.

Comment: what version of libc++ do you have? apparently clang added support for `.contains` for associative containers in version 13 of libc++. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support